# Excel function to calculate population in sub-regions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet containing the following four columns, each with ~18,000 rows:

1. **Sub-region code:** A geographic variable that has been used by my country's statistics bureau to create State and Federal regions.
2. **Region #1:** A column of ~90 State regions that correspond to each of the sub-region codes above.
3. **Region #3:** A column of ~60 Federal regions that correspond to each of the sub-regions.
4. **Population:** The estimated population of each of the sub-regions.

I have provided a simplified version of this spreadsheet in the image below:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a list of unique **Region #1** variables in one column, with a second adjacent column showing the unique **Region #2** variables that overlap the **Region #1** figures, and in a third column the total population within the overlapped **Region #1** and **Region #2** areas.

I can then manually calculate the percentage of the **Region #1** population that is in each **Region #2** area.

If possible, I would like a final product that looks similar to the (manually created) image below:

[image]

I am uncertain where to begin in order to perform this task, so would greatly appreciate any advice as to which function is best for such work.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure you can do it with [SUMIF()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) or [SUMIFS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function). And [this link](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) explains how to list the unique regions.

Comment: In the example image above I'm essentially wanting to determine what proportion of Albury's population (a state region) is present in two Federal regions (Farrer and Eden-Monaro). The regions have a common geography that is divided into very small sub-regions, so I need to add up all of the sub-regions that intersect both the State and relevant Federal region. I'm not sure if that clarifies things or makes it more complicated sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the PivotTable to get the result:

Create a PivotTable based on your data source and drag the fields to specific area, drag the field `Population` twice to `VALUES` area as shown in the following picture:

[Create PivotTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kESHR.jpg)

Then Right click the `Sum of Population2` and select `Value Field Settings`, select `Show Values as` tab and Select `% of Grand Total`:

[% of Grand Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWk2B.jpg)